# unable to start mysql after installing with homebrew

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I have a Mac Air with OS X 10.6.8 (10K540) and homebrew 0.8. I have installed MySql with `brew install mysql`. I have followed the instructions given by homebrew, specifically:

```
unset TMPDIR
mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
```

The problem now is starting the server. Homebrew says start mysqld manually with `mysql.server start`. When I try that, I get an error:

> The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/MICHAEL-ZELLMANNs-MacBook-Air.local.pid)

After doing some more research, I tried:

```
unset TMPDIR
mysql_install_db
```

But that gave me a FATAL_ERROR.

```
./bin/my_print_defaults
```

Some more data:

```
which mysql yields /usr/local/bin/mysql
mysql --version yields mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.14, for osx10.6 (i386) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: Hey did you solve it? I have exactly the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked a while ago but I had similar issues installing MySQL 5.6.19 via Homebrew on OSX Mavericks (10.9.3).

After several attempts, finally deleting the `*.err` file at `/usr/local/var/mysql` and running `mysql.server start` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the mysql error.log file for error messages.