# mysql 5.7 in Mac won't start - error doesn't give a clue

Tags: mysql, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I've tried installing mysql version 5.7 in my mac. (11.5.1 Big Sur). Installed it using brew and installation seemed successful but when I start it, nothing happens. It doesn't appear on the brew services list either after I start it. What worse is it doesn't give any reason why it was stopped

```
$ brew services start mysql@5.7
==> Successfully started `mysql@5.7` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7)
$ brew services list
Name       Status  User             File
mysql@5.7  stopped john.doe ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist
```

I did my research and tried doing the steps below but still the same result.

```
brew uninstall mysql@5.7
rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
rm /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
brew install mysql@5.7
brew link --force mysql@5.7
```

I did this like 4 times already but still the same result.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Check error logs https://serverfault.com/questions/42531/where-is-my-mysql-log-on-os-x

Comment: And ensure that there is no Mac native MySql pre-installed. If it is - stop that service and ensure it does not auto start

Comment: @Justinas THANK YOU! this worked -> "After several attempts, finally deleting the *.err file at /usr/local/var/mysql and running mysql.server start worked for me."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to start mysql after installing with homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635455/unable-to-start-mysql-after-installing-with-homebrew)